# Default CSS filename

Tags: css

for html, we have index.html, the file thats automatically loaded by the webserver if no filenames are specified.  Is there an equivalent for css, either from the webserver point of view, or just by convention?  surely it's not "index.css" right?

Thanks.

Update:
I guess I phrased my question a little poorly.  I already knew that css files would not  be loaded automatically.  I was just wondering if there was a strong convention for default css files.  Although there exists no strong convention, there are common names, as listed by the people who answered, some of which are:

- default.css
- main.css
- web.css
- style.css
- site.css

Or you can name the css file with the same filename as the html file that uses it.

Comment: `layout.css` or `design.css` can be considered as well..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No.

There are common names for the main stylesheet for a site, e.g. site.css or main.css, but no strong (or useful) convention.

Answer (score 11):

The name `style.css` starts to look odd as soon as you have more than one stylesheet. My 2 cents would be:

- `main.css` or `myappname.css` (e.g. `intranet.css`) for the app
- Something like `global.css` for a stylesheet shared between apps
- For css for individual pages, create subdirectories named after the pages so that you can easily see which css are shared and which are only used on certain pages

If you can, I'd recommend keeping it short and all lowercase without underscores / hyphens as it is less prone to typos.

Comment: And why people call it `style.css` instead of `styles.css`? Isn't that a style sheet consists of **many** styles?

Answer (score 7):

No there is no such thing. It probably is some "guidelines" to follow when designing templates for e.g. Joomla where you have "template.css" and so on. When I do not have such guidelines I normally name the default css "style.css", but this is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 5):

Can't think of a better default than **stylesheet.css** to match the value of the `rel` attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 4):

Since stylesheets can be loaded based on `media` attribute my file naming convention just follows the available options:

- `theme-media-all.css` - used for all media type devices
- `theme-media-print.css` - used for printers
- `theme-media-screen.css` - used for computers screens, tablets, phones, etc.
- `theme-media-speech.css` - used for screenreaders

You could omit the `media-` prefix but I like to be explicit both for myself years down the line or new developers coming to the project - plus you get filename grouping when sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard, because it's your HTML that decides which CSS file to reference rather than web server configuration.

With that said, it is a good idea to have a convention, so that your files are better organized.

For example, if you tie a CSS file with each file you might re-use the HTML file's name, but with the CSS extension.  (e.g. index.html has index.css or index.html.css.)

You could apply the same concept to directories or URL paths if your code is organized that way.  (e.g. /MyApp/MyFeature/MyFeature.css).

It's really up to you to decide, but it is important to be consistent, so others can understand your code more easily.

Hope this helps.